# Join inner directories with parent directory

Tags: python, file, filesystems

Given this directory structure:

```
└── names
    ├── name1
    │   └── subdir1
    │       ├── subnames
    │       │   └── cool
    │       │       ├── another-subdir1
    │       │       │   ├── file
    │       │       │   │   ├── file.txt
    │       │       │   ├── subnames
    │       │       │   │   ├── awesome
    │       │       │   │   │   └── another-subdir2
    │       │       │   │   │       ├── files
    │       │       │   │   │       │   ├── file.txt
    │       │       │   │   │       ├── subname
    │       │       │   │   │       │   └── super-awesome
    │       │       │   │   │       │       └── another-subdir3
    │       │       │   │   │       │           ├── file
    │       │       │   │   │       │           │   ├── file.txt
    │       │       │   │   └── great
    │       │       │   │       └── great-subdir1
    │       │       │   │           ├── random-name
    │       │       │   │           │   ├── file.txt
    └── name2
        └── subdir2
            ├── subnames
            │   └── nice
            │       ├── file.txt
```

I am trying to iterate through the whole directory structure but I am having a hard time to make it work.
I have tried below code but it does not exactly give what I want:

```
import os
def get_full_names(parent_dir):

    names = []
    for dir_name in os.scandir(parent_dir):
        if dir_name.is_dir():
            names.append(dir_name.name)
            subname_dir = os.path.join(parent_dir, dir_name.name)
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(subname_dir):
                if 'subnames' in dirs:
                    subnames = get_full_names(os.path.join(root, 'subnames'))
                    for subname in subnames:
                        names.append(f"{subname}-{dir_name.name}")
    return names
parent_dir = '/path/to/names'
names = get_full_names(parent_dir)
print(names)
```

This code gives:

```
['name1', 'cool-name1', 'great-cool-name1', 'awesome-cool-name1', 'super-awesome-awesome-cool-name1', 'super-awesome-cool-name1', 'great-name1', 'awesome-name1', 'super-awesome-awesome-name1', 'super-awesome-name1', 'name2', 'nice-name2']
```

Expected output:

```
['name1', 'cool-name1', 'awesome-cool-name1', 'super-awesome-awesome-cool-name1', 'great-cool-name1', 'name2', 'nice-name2']
```

In this case it should exclude `'super-awesome-cool-name1', 'great-name1', 'awesome-name1', 'super-awesome-awesome-name1' 'super-awesome-name1'` since:

super-awesome is not directly a subname/cool subdirectory

great is not directly a names/name1 sudirectory

awesome is not directly a names/name1 subdirectory

and so on...

The pattern will always be `names/parent-names-that-will-change/any-name-that-might-change/subnames/sub-parent-name/any-name-that-might-change/subnames/another-sub-parent-name/any-name-that-might-change/last-sub-dir-name`

Above example should become `last-sub-dir-name/another-sub-parent-name/sub-parent-name/parent-names-that-will-change`
Note that I have used slashes "/" just to differentiate the "-".

Basically, I just want to join the subnames according to it's direct parent subname directory up to the root parent directory (name1 and name2).

Comment: Use `os.path.walk()` instead of scanning the directories yourself.

Comment: *os.walk https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=walk#os.walk

Comment: Can you edit your question because your expected output of directory/sub-directory names don't match the directory map you included?

Comment: can you clarify the "rule" for determining which subdirectories? why does the expected output have `'super-awesome-awesome-cool-name1'` but not `'another-subdir3-super-awesome-subname-another-subdir2-awesome-subnames-another-subdir1-cool-subnames-subdir1-name1'`; and `'great-cool-name1'` but not `'great-another-subdir1-cool-subnames-subdir1-name1'`?

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer my solution.

My code:

```py
import os
from collections import deque

class Fake_Path(str):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__()
        if '\\' in value:
            value = value.replace('\\', '/')
        self.name = value.split('/')[-1]


def recur_get_names(cur_dir: str) -> list:
    names = deque()
    root = []
    parents = {'name', 'names', 'subname', 'subnames'}
    
    def worker(cur_dir: os.DirEntry, root: list, has_name: bool = False) -> None:
        if has_name:
            root = [cur_dir.name, *root]
            names.append(root)
        
        has_name = cur_dir.name in parents
        for p in os.scandir(cur_dir):
            if p.is_dir():
                worker(p, root, has_name)
    
    worker(Fake_Path(cur_dir), root)
    return [':'.join(name) for name in names]
```

Output:

```
In [918]: recur_get_names('D:/test/names')
Out[918]:
['name1',
 'cool:name1',
 'awesome:cool:name1',
 'super-awesome:awesome:cool:name1',
 'great:cool:name1',
 'name2',
 'nice:name2']
```

This problem is a very good case to use a simple recursive function, just put the actual work in the function proper, and recursively call the function itself.

By using colons you can always get back the names that made the output from the output.

In this case, to achieve what you want, you simply need to check if the current path is a directory, and if the current path is a directory, check if the parent path of current directory is in `{'name', 'names', 'subname', 'subnames'}`, if the parent is, the append the current name to `root` list, join the `root` using '-' in reverse order, and collect the result.

Since the parent name must contain `'name'`, and can have `sub` at the start and/or `s` at the end, this regex `'^(sub)?names?$'` can be used to validate such.

By iterating through the sub-directories of the current directory and calling the function recursively, it ensures all levels of the directory is traversed, and the first argument is a directory (unless of course if you called the function with a non-directory argument).

I created the test example using the following:

```
from pathlib import Path

files = [
    'D:/test/names/name1/subdir1/subnames/cool/another-subdir1/file/file.txt',
    'D:/test/names/name1/subdir1/subnames/cool/another-subdir1/subnames/awesome/another-subdir2/files/file.txt',
    'D:/test/names/name1/subdir1/subnames/cool/another-subdir1/subnames/awesome/another-subdir2/subname/super-awesome/another-subdir3/file/file.txt',
    'D:/test/names/name1/subdir1/subnames/cool/another-subdir1/subnames/great/great-subdir1/random-name/file.txt',
    'D:/test/names/name2/subdir2/subnames/nice/file.txt'
]

for file in files:
    Path(file).parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    Path(file).touch()
```

Directory structure:

```
PS D:\test> tree /f D:\test\names
Folder PATH listing for volume Tremillia
Volume serial number is 000000BD 4326:4555
D:\TEST\NAMES
├───name1
│   └───subdir1
│       └───subnames
│           └───cool
│               └───another-subdir1
│                   ├───file
│                   │       file.txt
│                   │
│                   └───subnames
│                       ├───awesome
│                       │   └───another-subdir2
│                       │       ├───files
│                       │       │       file.txt
│                       │       │
│                       │       └───subname
│                       │           └───super-awesome
│                       │               └───another-subdir3
│                       │                   └───file
│                       │                           file.txt
│                       │
│                       └───great
│                           └───great-subdir1
│                               └───random-name
│                                       file.txt
│
└───name2
    └───subdir2
        └───subnames
            └───nice
                    file.txt
```

---

### Edit

I have optimized my code as best as I could. Now It's as performant as the code in [blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6890912/blhsing)'s answer.

Comment: By the way the requirement is to join the names using dashes (-), this is bad because the names can contain dashes, so splitting by dash would not always give the the names that made the string. I  would suggest using colons (:) to fix this,  as colons aren't in the names and aren't valid path characters, so splitting by colons would always get back the input. But the OP wishes to use dashes so I cannot use colons.

Comment: The use of `re.match('^(sub)?names?$', cur_dir.parent.name)` unnecessarily incurs the overhead of regex-testing the same parent for every single child, not what I would call "elegant".

Comment: Also, making a system call with the `Path.is_dir` method on every single file is wasteful and slow. Much faster to use `os.scandir` to cache up such information for all files in an entire directory.

Comment: Also, why build the `root` list in a top-down order with `root = [*root, cur_dir.name]` only to waste time reversing it on the next line every single time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import os
import re

def getFullNames(parentDir):
    results = []
    for (path, _, _) in os.walk(parentDir):
        names = []
        names.extend(re.findall(r"(?:^names|subnames?)\\([^\\]+)", path))
        names.reverse()
        fullName = "-".join(names)
        if fullName not in results:
            results.append(fullName)

    return results[1:]
```

After building the directory structure you described and running `print(getFullNames("MY_PATH_TO_THE_PARENT_FOLDER"))`, I got your expected output:

```
['name1', 'cool-name1', 'awesome-cool-name1', 'super-awesome-awesome-cool-name1', 'great-cool-name1', 'name2', 'nice-name2']
```

Instead of trying to traverse the directory structure in a clever way, this iterates through every path `os.walk()` finds, uses a regex to calculate the name that path should generate, then adds it to the result list if it hasn't already been found.

To generate the names, it uses the rule that every subdirectory that is included in the name must be a direct child of a subdirectory named "subname" or "subnames".

Answer (score 0):

You can join names immediately under directories of names with `'subname'` in them with paths yielded by a recursivley traversing function. Make the recursive function take a flag as an additional argument to indicate whether the current given directory is supposed to yield directory names immediately under it so that you don't have to parse it again:

```
import os

def get_full_names(parent_dir):
    def _get_paths(parent_dir, contains_names=True):
        for entry in os.scandir(parent_dir):
            if entry.is_dir():
                if contains_names:
                    yield [entry.name]
                for path in _get_paths(entry.path, 'subname' in entry.name):
                    yield path + ([entry.name] if contains_names else [])
    return ['-'.join(path) for path in _get_paths(parent_dir)]
```

Given the directory structure in your question, the above function will return:

```
['name1', 'cool-name1', 'awesome-cool-name1', 'super-awesome-awesome-cool-name1', 'great-cool-name1', 'name2', 'nice-name2']
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/HeartyRegularReference